# Removing blank space behind tab when tab bar bar is removed

Tags: android

I'm developing an application in which I'd like the tab bar to appear and disappear based on the direction the user is scrolling. I use bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS); to show the tab bar and bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD); to hide the tabbar. The only problem is that when I hide the tab, it leaves behind a blank gray space (see second figure) instead of having the listview fill up the space. I also tried overlaying the actionbar by using requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY); but it didn't seem to help. I can provide any additional code needed. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

[image: With tabs in place]

[image: With tabs removed]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try removing all tabs and setting the navigation mode to standart:

```
actionBar.removeAllTabs();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
```